# Can a has_many :through association have other associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible for a has_many, through: assocation joined model to have associations ?
Lets say have this association where I have a list of products that has a lot of different prices where each price is linked to a country. So I can either get all the countries in which my product is available or each products available within a country.

**products**

```
has_many :prices
has_many :countries, through :prices
```

**prices**

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :country
```

**countries**

```
has_many :prices
has_many :products, through :prices
```

Now I want to add other associations on my price model, where prices has_one :currency, and where the price is defined by a user to which this information belongs. Is it possible to add association like this ?

**prices**

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :country

has_one :currency
belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if a simple "yes" will help you with your question, but (since you basically already provide the correct code): Yes.

Your `prices` join model is a default Rails model, so you can treat it like your other models (and implement associations, callbacks, custom finders, etc.). You just need to make sure that the foreign keys in your database tables line up correctly (`prices` needs a `user_id` column for example).

Not really part of the question, but a small remark:

I'm not sure that you want your prices to `has_one` currency though. This implies that the foreign key is in the `currencies` table (`price_id`) which in turn means that a currency `belongs_to` a price (maybe you rather want your currency to `has_many` prices and your price also `belongs_to` a currency).